# Silly question about elementary notions of Gravity and Electricity

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge

Consider then a book at rest in outer space. Obviously the book has a quantity of Mass and is Neutral with respect of Electric charge.So,Newtonian Gravity says that this very book generates a field called Gravitational field, or the Gravitational Mass (Gravitational Charge) generates Gravity.

Suppose now that this book "earn" some Electric charge. So, again, this book generates a field called Electric field, or the Electric charge generates Electricity.

- Is it correct what I said about the concept of charge (of gravity and electricity)?
- A electron generates gravitational field?

Comment: all masses generate gravitational fields, even one as small as the electron's. In addition the electron at rest has an electric field and if in motion a magnetic field . also the electron has a magnetic dipole moment, so even in its rest frame there is a magnetic field defined  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment . an electron is not a book, it is a quantum mechanical entity/particle  in the standard model of particle physics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model

Comment: Yes, you can interpret the mass of a particle as its gravitational charge, since according to Noether's theorem which states that for every symmetry there is a conserved quantity (called Noether charge), the gravitational theories have at least the translation symmetry of space-time, so that the energy-momentum is the conserved quantity. If the object is stationary then its gravitational charge will become its mass. In post-Newtonian approximation, its gravitational charges will become its mass while its momentum will not contribute. See for example https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0207254